# TCP Throughput testing tools with ability to rate-limit?

Tags: tcpip, throughput, rate-limits

I'm looking for test software that can generate test streams with the TCP/IP protocol, but limit the rate of the test data. For example, if using 100Mbps Ethernet, I would like to be able to generate a 1Mbps TCP/IP stream.

Tools like Iperf/Jperf can test with UDP at a specific rate, but TCP will always attempt to maximize its throughput.

Ideally, the tool would support Windows and IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nuttcp can limit the speed at which the transmitter sends data to the network. Check the -R option...

http://www.lcp.nrl.navy.mil/nuttcp/nuttcp.html

It´s part of pS-Performance Toolkit / BWCTL - Bandwidth Test Controller

http://psps.perfsonar.net/toolkit/